# Redirect URL to a path in the .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, shopware, shopware6

I want to redirect everything to "domain.tld/shop/...", but it always adds index.php to the URL "domain.tld/shop/index.php/..."

That's what I added at the beginning of the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Here is the whole .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Shopware
# The directives (lines) between "# BEGIN Shopware" and "# END Shopware" are dynamically generated. Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(?i:svg)$">
        Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'none'"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# END Shopware
```

Note: I tried it with that Condition as well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/
```

I've tried to place it in different locations in the file, but none of it worked either.

Answer (score -1):

To redirect everything to "domain.tld/shop/" using .htaccess, you can use the following code. Make sure to replace "domain.tld" with your actual domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The only difference is the RewriteCond, but I also tried the trailing slash.